# Why I can't use the KeyedByTypeCollection class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use the `System.Collections.Generic.KeyedByTypeCollection` ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)) in a WPF application but I get 
the

> the type or namespace name does not exist are you missing an assembly
>   reference

error, even if my class is using the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Note that you have to add an assembly reference of the assembly providing this type to your project. The documentation you referred to tells you which assembly that is (it's right there at the top of the documentation page).

Comment: Thanks, clearly I've no idea about `.NET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), the assemblies in which the type is defined are listed.

If you target the .NET Framework, you should add a reference to `System.ServiceModel.dll` from your WPF application. You do this by selecting it under Project->Add Reference->Assemblies->Framework in Visual Studio.